# Inequality involving Logarithmic Integral

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove the following inequality:

> $$ \int _2 ^x \frac{dt}{\log t} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log 2} + \frac{x - \sqrt{x}}{\log \sqrt{x}}$$

I was able to prove, for $t>-1,$ that
$$ \frac{t}{1+t} < \log (1+t) < t $$

but I am unsure on what to do next as this expression does not involve square roots. We also know that $\log x < \sqrt{x}.$ Any suggestions on how to proceed/conclude? (I am trying to prove this inequality for use in Number Theory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean $ x\ge 2$

This integral is $Li(x)+C$

By substitution that $T=\log t$, and integration by part,
becoming

$$ x^{-1}e^x-\int e^x  d(x^{-1}) $$

Substituting, we get $$\frac{x}{\log x} - \frac{e^2}{\log 2} -C(x)$$ 
$C(x)$ is the second integral that is in positive value, as for $ x\ge 2$,
$x^{-2}e^x \ge 0$ .

Also,  $\frac{e^2}{\log 2} \gt 0$

As we know for $x \ge 4 $,

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log 2}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log \sqrt{x}} \ge 0$

So the inequality becomes, 
$$\frac{x}{\log x} - C_1 \le \frac{x}{\log x} + C_2$$ 
, where $C_1,C_2$ are positive constants.

For $ 2 \lt x \lt 4 $, in

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log 2}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log \sqrt{x}} $$
since $\frac{1}{\log \sqrt x} =\frac{2}{\log x} \le \frac{2}{\log 2 }$,

as such, the expression becomes $ \frac {-\sqrt x}{\log 2} \ge \frac{-2}{\log 2}$, which is again $ \ge \frac{-e^2}{\log 2}$,

so the inequality still hold.